# Error Executing This Mysql Sp For Make Refresh Of The Fields Saved In Log Table Through Trigger But I Don't See The Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, dynamically-generated

This sp generate this Error but when I get the @queryString value and execute it, It's working:

> Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER `triggers_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `mydb`.`mytable` F' at line 2

This error is generated when I execute:

```
CALL prcTriggersLogsRefreshFields('mydb','mytable','myidtable');
```

This is the code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE "prcTriggersLogsRefreshFields";
CREATE PROCEDURE "prcTriggersLogsRefreshFields"(
    par_dbName text,
    par_tableName text,
    par_keyField text
)
BEGIN   
    SET @strJsonObj = null;
    SET @change_object = par_dbName||'.'||par_tableName;

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('\'',COLUMN_NAME, '\',', COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = par_dbName AND TABLE_NAME = par_tableName INTO @strJsonObj;

    SET @queryString = 'DROP TRIGGER `triggers_after_insert`;
                        CREATE TRIGGER `triggers_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `'||par_dbName||'`.`'||par_tableName||'` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('||@strJsonObj||')) change_obj FROM  `'||par_dbName||'`.`'||par_tableName||'` WHERE '||par_keyField||'=New.'||par_keyField||' INTO @jsonRow; 
                        INSERT INTO mylog_db.table_log (`change_id`, `change_date`, `db_name`, `table_name`, `change_object`, `change_event_name`, `previous_content`, `change_content`, `change_user`) VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), '''||par_dbName||''', '''||par_tableName||''', '''||@change_object||''', \'insert\', \'{}\', @jsonRow, New.user_created);
                        END;';
    
    -- select @queryString;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;
```

Comment: One thing at a time for MySQL prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html says:

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by `;` characters).

You have to run the statements one at a time if you use PREPARE.

There's no need to include the DROP TRIGGER in your prepared statement. You can run the DROP TRIGGER without prepare & execute, since there is no dynamic part in it. Then format the CREATE TRIGGER as a single statement and prepare and execute it.